# Does the complete SSL/TLS communication log prove that client sent all the data stored in log?

Tags: ssl, https

For the purposes of secrecy and authenticity of communications I use SSL / TLS (https) with client certificate. If I log the entire SSL traffic on the server side, is the SSL log sufficient evidence that the communication between the server and the other side with client certificate was exactly as it is recorded in the log? At the beginning an asymmetric handshake is used but further communication continues with symmetric encryption. Symmetric encryption would not mind if one of the messages cannot be forged on the receiving side. As a server I know the symmetric key so it should be able for me to spoof one of the messages sent by the client, shouldn't it? What algorithm and what special settings shall I use, so that client could not say that he sent a different message than what I recorded in the log?

Comment: MAC assures integrity only, not authenticity. I probably need asymmetric signing of symmetrically encrypted messages - does any cipher suite support that? Is it possible to enforce browser to use this signing? Any other idea?

Answer (score 2):

Logging anything (including data from SSL) does not proof the origin of the data. In theory you've could made up the data yourself. Even logging the complete SSL traffic including the necessary encryption key does not proof anything  because in most cases this could have been made up too.

It might be acceptable as a proof if the whole SSL traffic is logged including the encryption key and if a client certificate was used for authentication (i.e. two-way SSL). The real client certificate owned by the client is a part you can not make up yourself. But there is still no guarantee that some judge would accept it as proof. And of course the client could try to deny that this is its own client certificate which was used.

Comment: I'm using two-way SSL and it's assured that the client certificate belongs to the person that is identified in the certificate.